# JPA supporting databases - Defined by JPA or it's up to the provider?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've a simple question, I know that if you use `JPA` only methods you can change the database from `MySQL` to `Derby` without having to worry with changing your code.

My question is, all the supported databases are defined by `JPA` or it is up to the provider to support them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA is a spec and does not provide implementation for specific databases. So the question of supported databases is really about the provider that you are using with JPA (Hibernate or EclipseLink etc).

If you are using Hibernate, see the supported databases [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases2).

Comment: But if I restrict my usage to only JPA defined methods, I can change the provider without changing my code. Right?

Comment: Yes. That is one of the advantage of using JPA on top of ORM implementation.

Comment: Then if I want to change my database from MySQL to X and X is not supported by my current JPA Provider I can change to another JPA Provider that supports database X without changing my code. Correct? (I hope you did follow my thinking here:) )

Comment: There will be configuration changes required to support it. But again you will not need to rewrite your code to accomplish this.